# Access Criteria Problems

Tags: date, datetime, criteria

I have an access database which is basically a downtime log holds information like date / start / end / duration / department / area /

Okay, so I have a problem with the date part. In my query, I used an expression to abstract the date from the field start using format([start]-0.25,"DD/MM/YYYY")

The -0.25 is an indicator that checks if the time is between 00:00:00 and 06:00:00 if so gives the previous day's date.

From this field, I base a report which uses form filters to filter out by the day however if I use a date range it only filters by the "DD" and not the "DD/MM/YYYY".

For instance if I put 01/09/2015 and 20/09/2015 every date that is between 01 and 20 will show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the formula incorrect I got it working by adding a text box to the entry form and using the formula within that then when it was submitted the data was just the date.